# convert string in format dd-mm-yy to dd-mm-yyyy in bash

Tags: bash, date-formatting

How can I convert a date in format dd-mm-yy to dd-mm-yyyy in bash? for example, if my string is 28-12-14, I want it in this other format 28-12-2014

Answer (score 3):

You can use just simple string manipulation:

```
d="28-12-14"
d2="${d:0:6}20${d:6:2}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert dates using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
DT1=28-12-14
dy1=${DT1%%-*}; DT1=${DT1#*-}
mo1=${DT1%%-*}; DT1=${DT1#*-}
DT2=$(date --date=$DT1-$mo1-$dy1 +%d-%m-%Y)
echo $DT2
```

Output is

```
28-12-2014
```